# How does the condition (Expression-2) of this for loop work?

Tags: c++, for-loop, static

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int fun()
{
  static int num = 16;
  return num--;
}
 
int main()
{
  for(fun(); fun(); fun())
  cout<< fun()<<" ";
  return 0;
}

Output : 14 11 8 5 2
```

How does the condition (expression-2) of the for loop work? I mean, why does it terminate when fun returns 0 (num becomes -1)?

Comment: When converting int to bool, 0 becomes false, any other value becomes true.
> C++14 §4.12/1 “A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;

Comment: #include <bits/stdc++.h> is not a real header, please don't use this

Comment: A `for` loop can be converted to a `while` loop. A `for` loop like `for (A; B; C) { D; }` would be `A; while (B) { D; C; }`. In your specific case it would be `fun(); while (fun()) { fun(); fun(); }`. It might make it easier to follow along and see what's happening. And much easier to use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement.

Comment: I believe that this is effectively a duplicate of the basic "how does a `for` loop work?" question. In a nutshell, you can replace `for` with pseudocode that makes its functioning much clearer for someone unfamiliar with it. ETA: basically what @Someprogrammerdude said

Comment: This would be a more interesting question if you asked why is it an infinite loop if `num` is initialized to 17, but terminates correctly with 16.

Answer (score 0):

The condition statement is evaluated *before* entering the body of the loop. In your case, the statement evaluates to `true`, and the loop body is executed, **if** `fun()` returns a non-zero value.

To see this clearly, modify your code as follows:

```
int fun( const char* name)
{
  static int num = 16;
  cout << name << ":" << num << "\n";
  return num--;
}

int main()
{
  for(fun("init"); fun("test"); fun("iterate"))
    cout<< fun("body")<<" ";
  return 0;
}
```